# How do I create a collapsible like Bootstrap in AMP?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, amp-html

I am trying to create a collapsible in AMP with a sleek animation like Bootstrap has.

Now, I can create a collapsible with toggling a class and adjusting some height with CSS, but if I do so I will be giving a fixed height for all the collapsible, and since the content height won't be same for all the block, I cannot give the height.

In JavaScript, I could calculate the height of the content, and animate the height accordingly, but since we cannot use JavaScript in AMP, is there any way to do this?

I have tried doing it with css. I defined two classes one that hides the content by setting height to 0, and another shows the content by setting height to auto. It works, but it didn't have any animation. However, If I set height to some pixels instead of auto, and add some css transition, it works. But I don't want to give some static height for all the block.

```
<!- Hidden -->
<div class="rich-text-block">
   <h3>Pathological Criteria</h3>
   <div class="richtext-content">If either is positive, diagnosis is definite (see Reference for exceptions)</div>
</div>
```

```
<!- Shown -->
<div class="rich-text-block shown">
   <h3>Pathological Criteria</h3>
   <div class="richtext-content">If either is positive, diagnosis is definite (see Reference for exceptions)</div>
</div>
```

```
.rich-text-block .richtext-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s linear;
    height: 0;
}
rich-text-block.shown .richtext-content {
    height: auto;
}
```

I hope I am clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use amp-accordion?

Comment: @JayGray thanks, I will check with amp-accordion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [amp-accordion](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-accordion) for your use case.

Coming to your issue. 
You can not transition height with value `auto`. You can use `max-height` in the `transition` and set a max-height to something bigger than your box height will ever get.

The problem with this approach is transition will be based on `max-height` so if the height of all your boxes is almost the same, all the transitions will look almost identical, but if the heights of all your boxes are very much different then the transition duration of all your boxes won't look identical.

```
.rich-text-block .richtext-content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
}
rich-text-block.shown .richtext-content {
    max-height: 50px;
}
```